# SyntaxHighlighter treats < > sign as HTML tags

Tags: drupal-7, syntax-highlighting

this image describes my problem, This is a C code, which is the following one.

```
<pre class="brush: cpp">
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world<imnew>");

    return 0;
}
</pre>
```

What I get as node output is the following.

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, although I did not check "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" filter.
But I found a temporal solution by escaping first less than character to <

```
<pre class="brush:cpp">
 #include &lt;iostream> 

  using namespace std;
  void main()
   {
   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;   cout << "Welcome to C++ Programming" << endl; }
</pre>
```

Or you can generate [custom filter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter)  to escape greater and less than sembols to
`&gt;` an `&lt;`

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with the "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" input filter that is executed after the Syntax highlighter input filter. The code executed from the "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" input filter is the following one.

```
return filter_dom_serialize(filter_dom_load($text));
```

I tried executing the following code.

```
$text = <<<HTML
<pre class="brush: cpp">
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world<imnew>");

    return 0;
}
</pre>
HTML;

print filter_dom_serialize(filter_dom_load($text));
```

The output I got is the following one.

```
<pre class="brush: cpp">
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world<imnew>");

    return 0;
}
</imnew></stdio.h></pre>
```

The reason is exactly that `<stdio.h>`, and `<imnew>` are interpreted as tags, and they are closed before `</pre>`. The syntax highlighter should escape any `<`, and `>` found inside the code to avoid such problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @guneysus answer, changing all < to &lt; also worked.